# Logitech Illuminated K800 keyboard not working properly after boot-up

Tags: keyboard

When I boot my machine, my Logitech Illuminated K800 keyboard connected via a Unifying Receiver does not work properly: there is lag between a keypress and the letter appearing on the screen and some letters are not registered at all.

I can fix it by unplugging and replugging the receiver but that is tiresome. Any ideas what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, all I needed in the end was installing an updated version of the solaar package from here: https://launchpad.net/~solaar-unifying/+archive/ubuntu/ppa